# Disconnect Windows Account from Computer's local account on Windows 10

Tags: windows

There is a really good answer here for disconnecting my computer from Microsoft when I had Windows 8.1.  I am now upgraded to Windows 10.  Is the fix the same?  I cannot even access my computer anymore because I don't know what password Microsoft has chosen to assign to me!  Without my work computer, I am dead in the water.  Help!

Comment: "There is a really good answer here for disconnecting my computer from Microsoft" - Yes there is.  You simply disconnected the account.  You disconnect your account basically the exact same way.  You still need to determine what your password to your Microsoft Account is to solve your problem.